How to сolorize LaTeX code using Piton package
How to сolorize LaTeX code using Piton package?
Comment should be orange.
I just need a good Latex code coloring that will work on any document.
There seems to be a problem with symbols: % _
MWE:
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{piton}

\PitonOptions{
    line-numbers={
        skip-empty-lines=false,
        label-empty-lines=true,     
        format=\footnotesize\color{black}
    },
    break-lines,
    indent-broken-lines,
    detected-commands={highLight},
}

\SetPitonStyle
{
% Tag = \color{blue},
 String = \color{black},    
 Keyword = \color{blue},
 Comment = \color{orange},
}

\NewPitonLanguage{LaTeX}
{
 morekeywords = {documentclass, usepackage, title, author, date, begin, end, maketitle},
 keywordsprefix=\, 
%alsoletter= _,
% morecomment=[l]\%,
}
%========================
\begin{document}
\begin{Piton}[language=LaTeX, line-numbers, auto-gobble]
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[main=russian,english]{babel}
\title{Sample document in \LaTeX{}}
\author{Ivanov\,V.V.}
\date{20~February~2020\,year}
\begin{document}
% create a title (comment)
    \maketitle
    Sample document with \textbf{FIO}!
\end{document}
\end{Piton}
\end{document}



could you clarify what output you expected? is it that the wrong things are orange?

Added an explanation to the question. @cfr

if you just want something which works, using e.g. listings might be easier than piton as it includes definitions for TeX, LaTeX etc. out-of-the-box. (or minted is also popular, but I've never used it personally.)

are there fonts in texlive we can use to reproduce this? I'm not sure what to substitute for russian code listings. the fonts in your example are presumably system fonts I don't have.

For me the answer of François did not work for some reason. What did work was to temporarily change the catcode of % to a normal character during the language definition, and then use morecomment=[l]% (without the escape character). Note that this means you cannot use % to add comments to the definition itself.
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[main=russian,english]{babel}
%========================================
\babelfont{rm}[Scale=0.976]{DejaVu Serif}
\babelfont{tt}[Scale=0.976]{Ubuntu Sans Mono}
%========================================
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{piton}

\PitonOptions{
    line-numbers={
        skip-empty-lines=false,
        label-empty-lines=true,     
        format=\footnotesize\color{black}
    },
    break-lines,
    indent-broken-lines,
    detected-commands={highLight},
}

\SetPitonStyle
{
 %Tag = \color{blue},
 String = \color{black},    
 Keyword = \color{blue},
 Comment = \color{orange},
}

\begingroup
\catcode`\%=12
\NewPitonLanguage{LaTeX}
{
 morekeywords = {documentclass, usepackage, title, author, date, begin, end, maketitle},
 keywordsprefix=\\,
 morecomment=[l]%
}
\endgroup
%========================
\begin{document}
\begin{Piton}[language=LaTeX, line-numbers, auto-gobble]
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[main=russian,english]{babel}
\title{Пример документа в \LaTeX{}}
\author{Иванова\,В.В.}
\date{20~февраля~2020\,года}
\begin{document}
% создаем заголовок
    \maketitle
    Пример документа с \textbf{ФИО} автора и датой создания!
\end{document}
\end{Piton}
\end{document}

Result:

Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249890/.

In versions of piton at least 4.2a (2024-12-06), you can write :
 keywordsprefix=\\, 
 morecomment=[l]{\%}

% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{piton}

\PitonOptions{
    line-numbers={
        skip-empty-lines=false,
        label-empty-lines=true,     
        format=\footnotesize\color{black}
    },
    break-lines,
    indent-broken-lines,
    detected-commands={highLight},
}

\SetPitonStyle
{
 String = \color{black},    
 Keyword = \color{blue},
 Comment = \color{orange},
}

\NewPitonLanguage{LaTeX}
{
 morekeywords = {documentclass, usepackage, title, author, date, begin, end, maketitle},
 keywordsprefix=\\, 
 morecomment=[l]{\%}
}
%========================
\begin{document}
\begin{Piton}[language=LaTeX, line-numbers, auto-gobble]
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[main=russian,english]{babel}
\title{Sample document in \LaTeX{}}
\author{Ivanov\,V.V.}
\date{20~February~2020\,year}
\begin{document}
% create a title (comment)
    \maketitle
    Sample document with \textbf{FIO}!
\end{document}
\end{Piton}
\end{document}



Your solution doesn't work for me. Marijn's solution works. Do I need the morekeywords list? Or can I do without it?@F. Pantigny

@Youra_P: In fact. I was wrong. My code doesn't work with the current version of piton (v. 4.2). However, I have posted on CTAN a new version of piton (4.2a, 2024/12/06) and, in that version, my code works.
